# Spark SQL: NoSuchMethodError: SQLContext.load

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm getting a NoSuchMethodError when running a simple Spark program, trying to read in a CSV from HDFS.

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.load(Ljava/lang/String;Lscala/collection/immutable/Map;)Lorg/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame;
```

The code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext

object Averager{
        def main (args: Array[String]) {
                val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Averager")
                val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

                val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)

                val df = sqlContext.load("com.databricks.spark-csv", Map("path" -> "hdfs://hadoop:9000/file.csv", "header" -> "true"))

                df.printSchema()
        }
}
```

And my project.sbt file:

```
name := "Averager"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.5"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.6.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.databricks" % "spark-csv_2.10" % "1.5.0"
```

It compiles fine with sbt package, but when run it fails and prints out that error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm wondering whether you're using incompatible versions. can you paste your spark submit here

Comment: @RamGhadiyaram I'm just doing `spark-submit --master=local[*] file.jar`.

Comment: Seems I was actually using Scala 2.11 and my whole sbt file was rubbish. I updated it to use 2.11 builds of everything but now I get this error with spark-csv:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark-csv. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html`

Answer (score 0):

Starting in Spark 2.x, the spark-csv package is already included with Spark.

You should just be able to do:

val df=spark.read.option("header","true").csv("file.csv")

If you are using Spark 1.6.x, there is no load method on SQLContext, you need to use read():

val df = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")...

Hope that helps.